# how to implement arc menu to my project?

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I am new to android and i am trying to make a radial menu(arc menu) which has an image in the center and other images around it.

I got a library online but i do not know how to use it or even how to import it to my project. i tried following the instructions given online but failed.

All i have got till now is a list array of String that contains the path to the images and the first element is the image to be set in the center.

the library can be found here: https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

P.S. i am using eclipse.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You say you tried following the instructions.. what happened?

Answer (score 0):

There plenty of libraries for that, just go over some of them in [Libraries For Developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos)

If you are new to Android switch to Android Studio.. Eclipse is .. mm.. kind of abandoned by Google

After you decide on the library you need to better explain the problem you are having, it's not very clear what's not working for you

Comment: i have already selected a library. it is given in the link i provided. i just wanna know how to use it.